# Find the riskless rate in the model

Tags: probability

Consider the binomial model of the price of a share of stock of XYZ corporation defined as follows. 
The current price is $S_0=100$. Time is discrete, and the time periods are labeled $t=0,1,2,\ldots,10$. 
The price of an XYZ share at time $t$ is denoted by $S_t$ (it is a random variable) for each $0\le t\le 10$.

At each time $t\le9$, the stock price will either increase by a factor of $5/4$ with probability $45\%$, 
or decrease by a factor of $5/4$ with probability $55\%$, before the following time $t+1$. For example, the 
possible values of $S_1$ are $125$ and $80$, and the possible values of $S_2$ are $156.25, 100$ and $64$.

Find the riskless rate in the model described above.

I tried $((5/4)+(5/4))/2-1=.25$ but it wasn't right. I'm not sure how else to set it up. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the upper and lower probability are all $5/4$? I think one of them should be $4/5$.

Comment: That is what the question says.

Comment: I think there some typo in your question. Because the product of upper and lower ratio should be $1$.

Comment: @MPW Yes, I just mean growth factors. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Sorry, I think I get your meaning.

Answer (score 0):

There are some of my views. I do not know if it is valid of what I say.

The risk free rate of this model can be solve by calculate the expectation of share price at $t_{10}$. Firstly, we have the following formula for your model by using binomial model.
\begin{equation}
E[S_{t_k}]=\sum_{i=0}^kC_k^i S_{t_0}(p_u u)^i(p_d d)^{k-i}=S_{t_0}(p_uu+p_dd)^k
\end{equation}
where $p_u$ and $p_d$ are the upper and lower probabilities and $u$ and $d$ are upper and lower ratios respectively. So, take your data in this formula, we can solve the risk free rate  that given by
\begin{equation}
S_{t_0}(1+r/k)^k=S_{t_0}(p_uu+p_dd)^k\\
r=0.025=2.5\%
\end{equation}
Alternatively, you can solve the rate by a continuous type that set the LHS of the equality by $S_{t_0}e^{rt}$.

Comment: Dear @Lion $0.00249$ is $0.249 \%.$

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani That is my mistake. Thank your for your correction. I have edit my answer.

Comment: are you sure this answer is correct?

Comment: @user130417 No. As the beginning of my answer, this is only my view. And i also hope the correct answer.